Custom QAbstractItemModel or QAbstractItemView like explorer
I've been experimenting with the model view concept in qt and c++ for some time now. My goal is to present the data in a table like Windows file explorer can do...
There is no problem with tabular data presentation. It only occurs when the cursor is implemented...
The cursor breaks into individual cells in both QTreeView and QTableView.
No matter how I try, every time the cursor breaks up into individual cells, which can at least be controlled with the cursor keys. But I don't want this behavior. I don't want to work with individual cells at all, and the gui "shouldn't" allow cells to be selected, marked, moved around in them, etc... (even if the cells had editing disabled).
Only the treeview option in the basic settings works correctly. Once I enable multiple row selection. The cursor immediately breaks into cells.
I am wondering which solution is correct in the end. If this behavior affects the model (data is not stored in rows with one column but in rows and columns) or if this behavior affects the view.
I am also thinking about whether it is possible to somehow configure and modify qtreeview or whether to create a completely new view based on qtreeview or qtableview
Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've already consulted ChatGpt, it's a great help, but it couldn't help me with this. Maybe I asked him the wrong questions.
Test code here:
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTreeView>
#include <QTableView>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QStandardItem>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
QApplication app(argc, argv);

// Create base layout
QWidget mainWidget;
QVBoxLayout layout(&mainWidget);

// Create 3 rows and 3 columns model
QStandardItemModel model(3, 3);
model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels({"Code", "Name", "Description"});

// insert data
for (int row = 0; row < 3; ++row)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < 3; ++column)
    {
        QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(QString("Data %1").arg(row * 3 + column + 1));
        model.setItem(row, column, item);
    }
}

// Create QTreeView
QTreeView view1;
view1.setModel(&model);
view1.setRootIndex(model.index(-1, 0));
view1.setRootIsDecorated(false); // Hide expand/collapse ikon

view1.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
view1.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection);



// Create QListView
QTableView view2;
view2.setModel(&model);
view2.setRootIndex(model.index(-1, 0));

view2.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
view2.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection);

layout.addWidget(&view1);
layout.addWidget(&view2);

mainWidget.show();

return app.exec();
}

Bad example:

Ideal target solution:

Since I'm not a complete professional, it's quite difficult for me to determine which object is best for achieving the goal. It seems that no object (QTreeView, QListView, QTableView) is correct and I need to create a completely new custom view.

QTreeView is primarily built for a tree structure, so I need to remove all tree elements
QTableView is primarily built to work with cells, so I need to rebuild it from cells to rows
QListView uses only one column, so I need to implement a multi-column feature.

It almost seems to me that I should create some new view (MyRowView) that combines QTableView and QTreeView.
Can you advise me how to do it?
Addition:
To be unclear. I know that index and cursor are two things. But I need to work with whole rows. I just need to know that I'm standing on line X, I don't need column information for anything.
If you look at the BASIC settings of QTreeView, it is not possible to get the "selected row" and "current index" to be different from each other (desired behavior). But then I turn on multi-line marking and suddenly the two are separated.
It's not just about "bad" behavior, it's also about the fact that you can't do anything like that with programs like Explorer. You cannot get the current index for example on the file "size" column in File Explorer. You can't get it at "writetime" either.
Whether you're clicking the mouse, moving the cursor keys, multi-line marking, you're still in full-line(row) mode. But I can't achieve this concept in QT :-(.
And I don't know if problem is in model, or in view. If I must create own new View, or use any existing object(treeview, tableview) + setting any property?

You can find pretty good explanation how to do it in the documentation.

So you think the problem is in the model?

Improve a title, since it is to general comparing to your actual problem (I must admit at first didn't read details). There are ready solutions. Just try: QFileSystemModel and see some example.
Alos check out flags and its possible values (in case QFileSystemModel doesn't do this as you desire).

I tested the QFileSystemModel as well. It doesn't work. I still need to put the result in a QTreeView or QTableView, where the cursor breaks down into individual cells. That's why I'm asking if anyone has any idea where the problem is. If I should search in model or view.

I find your question unclear. Are you talking about keyboard navigation and focus? The first image you're showing displays a selected row and a current index, which are two distinct aspects (even if sometimes they match). Also: how the view shows its contents also depends on the model: a QListView can even show a tree model (but it will be shown as a simple list of a specific parent), similarly to QTableView, as much as QTreeView could show a table (if using an appropriate parent that only has one level of children). But this doesn't seem relevant to the problem you're having.

@exo I've provided hints how to change behavior of QFileSystemModel override flags function. Can' t provide full example, since currently do not have machine with Qt installed.

@exo It's unclear if your issue is graphical or logical. In the first case, the way in which selection and the current index are drawn depends on the current style. In fact, with the "Oxygen" style on Linux I always get the full row selected with no highlight on the current index whatsoever. There can be ways to work around this, but a custom item delegate would be required. If the issue is logical (which index is the current one) then clarify why is this a problem for you, since it's quite easy to get the sibling of the current index, and therefore retrieve the one in the first column.

@MarekR thx for "flags and their possible values". I will check it.

@musicamante It's just a graphic look for me. I need to make object (view) that will behave like a list of files in windows explorer.

@exo Then using an item delegate is the correct approach. It may be sufficient to override initStyleOption() and properly update the option state. Unfortunately, I don't use Windows (and I cannot code in C++), so I cannot tell you if doing that will be 100% sufficient, nor how you can achieve it. I suggest you to look into the QStyle documentation and do related research about item delegates and how their different states affect drawing.
